# align 3 images center in div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

i have code html using angular material library:

```html
<div layout="row"   layout-wrap  style="background: yellow; ">
    <div  ng-repeat="pro in Products"   >
      <md-card class="cardProduct" >
        <img ng-src={{pro.Image1}} class="md-card-image imageProduct">
      </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

it shows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2NCh.png)
I want it align center, and the fourth image is in the left, not center.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using angular material you can easily do this with flex-box
It will help if there are more images to come
Change your  `html` code as

**HTML:**

```
<div layout="row"   layout-wrap  style="background: yellow; ">
        <div class="prod-container"  ng-repeat="pro in Products"   >
            <md-card class="cardProduct" flex="30" >
                <img   ng-src={{pro.Image1}} class="md-card-image imageProduct">
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.prod-container{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-contents: flex-start;
  }
```

you can also give css for the cards by removing `flex=30` from the `html` code

`<md-card class="cardProduct">`

and the **CSS** will be

```
.cardProduct{
  min-width: 30%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I have resolve my problem. I make css: justify-content: space-between;

Answer (score 0):

just make the `text-align` property of the parent of the images to `center`.

```
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent container (layout="row") have the css property:

```
text-align: center;
```

And the ng-repeated containers have the property:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and in case you have any text for those containers might want a:

```
text-align: left;
```